# Vertically align nested rows using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4, I am having problems vertically aligning nested rows while trying to utilize `align-items-start` and `align-items-end`, respectively.

[image: Image of desired layout. There is one large square the height of the window taking up the left half of the space. To the right of the large square are two wide, short rectangles. The first one is aligned to the top of the square on the left. The second one is below the first and is aligned with the bottom of the square on the left.]

Here is my current code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-around">

    <div class="col-sm-2 align-self-center"> <!-- Left side col -->
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-8"> <!-- Right side col -->
      <div class="row align-items-start" style="background-color:gray;"> <!-- Upper right row -->
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, upper left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, upper right</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row align-items-end" style="background-color:orange;"> <!-- Lower right row -->
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, lower left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, lower middle</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, lower right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SIRmisterD/x1hphsvb/17/

As far as I can tell when I inspect the element, the parent column (the `col-sm-8` line) is correctly sized in relation to the left side column (`col-sm-2`) as they both have the same height. However, as soon as the two nested rows are introduced, the `align-items-xxx` classes are not being utilized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having the `align-items-*` classes for the rows will only affect their content, but not their own position. To achieve the desired effect, the parent of the two rows (the `.col-sm-8` element) needs to have three classes:

- `d-flex`: make the column itself a flexbox (by default, only rows have `display: flexbox` in Bootstrap 4)
- `flex-column`: show children from top to bottom instead of left to right
- `justify-content-between`: make the children have space in between

  - This might seem wrong, as normally `justify-content-between` is applied to the X / main axis, but as we have already applied the `flex-column` class, the effect of this class will be inversed as well, affecting the Y axis instead

Inserting these three classes to the column and removing the unnecessary ones from the rows will achieve your desired layout.

Your updated snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row justify-content-around align-items-stretch">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <!-- Left side col -->
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
      <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
      <!-- Right side col -->
      <div class="row" style="background-color:gray;">
        <!-- Upper right row -->
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, upper left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, upper right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row" style="background-color:orange;">
        <!-- Lower right row -->
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, lower left</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, lower middle</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <p>Right col, lower right</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And [the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siavasfiroozbakht/tk7p7j4r/) as well.

It seems that two Bootstrap style sheets are imported into the Fiddle, one of v4 and a customised Flatly one of v3 – **this might cause issues as styling is applied from both classes, so it's best to keep the version 4 only.**

For more information on flexbox, learn more from [the guide at CSS-Tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and about [the Bootstrap 4 Grid System](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/).

Comment: This worked perfectly when I implemented it into my project. However, more importantly than just the achieving the desired outcome, the explanation is very clear and it definitely helped me to understand where I was going wrong. Thank you, @Siavas.

Comment: My pleasure to help, @SIRmisterD.